# Pandas DataFrame Index by Month?

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if this is possible using pandas.  However I would like to make a DataFrame as follows.
Except I only want to have months and days in the index without years.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 4), index=pd.date_range('1-1', periods=12, freq='M'), columns=['2007', '2008', '2009', '2010'])
```

Just to give a little more info.  I have done the following.

```
df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(72), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=72, freq='M'))
```

Then I can use grouby as follows:

```
groupYear_Month = df.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.month)).sum()
```

Which yields:

```
groupYear_Month.head()
Out[9]: 
(2000, 1)    1.077949
(2000, 2)   -0.563224
(2000, 3)   -2.016833
(2000, 4)   -0.140693
(2000, 5)    2.113549
dtype: float64
```

Now I can:

```
groupYear_Month.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(groupYear_Month.index)
```

However, this kills the date format.  For example I don't get a two month 01, 02 ... 12.
I can unstack it now and get the years at the column level.

```
groupYear_Month.unstack(0)
```

This works but it is no longer a date index.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure you can do it. If you check `df.index.month.dtype` (or `.year`), it is `int32`. I guess the date format is gone for good. But if you just need two digit for month, you just need `groupYear_Month = df.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, str(x.month).zfill(2))).sum()`. Anyway, date index has to be regenerated.

Comment: Thanks.  The zfill is a great suggestion.  I was hoping that I can have dates without a year but in someways that just seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution would be to write a small class:

```
class Month:
    __slots__ = ['month', 'year']
    def __init__( self, date ):
        self.month, self.year = date.month, date.year

    def __repr__( self ):
        return '{}-{:0>2}'.format( self.year, self.month )

    def __lt__( self, other ):
        return self.year < other.year or self.year == other.year and self.month < other.month
```

then:

```
>>> df.groupby( Month ).sum( )
2000-01   -1.66
2000-02    0.37
2000-03    0.85
...
2005-11   -0.30
2005-12   -0.93
Length: 72, dtype: float64
```